# how to set a default image to a user with mongoose y node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an application with some functionality similar to twitter where the user posts text and images.
I want to give the user a default profile picture in case he doesn't have one, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I created a schema image where I wrote the following code but I don't know how to continue to make what I want to implement work:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    photo: { type: Array, default:  ['https://wallpapers-clan.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/cute-pusheen-pfp-1.jpg'] }
});
```

This is the user schema I created:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const saltRounds = 10;


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: { type: String, require: true },
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, require: true },
    salt: { type: String, require: true },

    followers: [{
            type: 'ObjectId',
            ref: 'User'
          }],
    following: [{
        type: 'ObjectId',
        ref: 'User'
      }],
    posts: [
      {
        type: 'ObjectId',
        ref: 'Post'
      }
    ]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

I created a schema image but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track

Answer (score 0):

If your users can only have one profile picture it's not necessary to create a new schema just for the profile picture. You could store the image as an URL in the user schema, that way when you load the user's document you also get their profile picture.

You could add the following field to your existing user schema:

```js
profilePicture: {
    type: String,
    default: 'https://example.com/cute-pusheen.jpg' // Add a default value
},
```

In this case if you don't specify an image when creating the user the defualt value will be used.